# How to trigger JetPack recomposition when state is re-assigned it's current value

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

The below code works as desired: the canvas gets recomposed each time the user either clicks the canvas itself or clicks the topBar icon, no matter how many times or in what order. In addition, the state variable value reveals something I want to know: where the user clicked. (Values 0 and 1 mean the icon was clicked and values 2 and 3 mean the canvas).

However, if the canvasState and iconState variables are set to their respective V1 functions instead of the V2 functions, then clicking the canvas or icon multiple times in a row is not detected. Apparently this is because the V1 functions can re-assign the same value to the state variable, unlike the V2 functions.

Since I'm using the neverEqualPolicy(), I thought I didn't have to assign a different value to the state variable to trigger a recompose. As a noob to Kotlin and Compose, what am I misunderstanding?

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyApp()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MyApp() {
    var state by remember { mutableStateOf(value = 0, policy = neverEqualPolicy()) }
    val canvasStateV1 = { state = 0 }
    val iconStateV1 = { state = 2 }
    val canvasStateV2 = { state = if (state == 0) { 1 } else { 0 } }
    val iconStateV2 = { state = if (state == 2) { 3 } else { 2 } }
    val iconState = iconStateV2
    val canvasState = canvasStateV2
    Scaffold(
        topBar = { TopBar(canvasState) },
        content = { padding ->
            Column(Modifier.padding(padding)) {
                Screen(state, iconState)
            }
        }
    )
}

@Composable
fun TopBar(iconState: () -> Unit) {
    TopAppBar(
        title = { Text("This is a test") },
        actions = {
            IconButton(onClick = { iconState() }) {
                Icon(Icons.Filled.AddCircle, null)
            }
        }
    )
}

@Composable
fun Screen(state: Int, canvasState: () -> Unit) {

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .aspectRatio(ratio = 1f)
                .background(color = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface)
                .pointerInput(Unit) {
                    detectTapGestures(
                        onTap = { canvasState() },
                    )
                }
        ) {
            Canvas(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().clipToBounds()
            ) {
                Log.d("Debug", "Canvas: state = $state")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I didn't know other things to try to get the neverEqualPolicy() to work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the main reason for this is because the function Screen() is skippable. If you add the state as a MutableState instead of the Int itself, you will see that the Log.d gets called each time the state value gets updated. Same goes for merging the Screen() function into Column in MyApp

Compose analyses each function during build time. The screen functions receives an integer value, this is an immutable value, so the function itself becomes skippable.

To analyse which function is skippable/stable (and which is not), you can run a report during the build phase
[This repo shows how](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/androidx-main/compose/compiler/design/compiler-metrics.md#enabling-metrics)

**EDIT:**
In this example you have two buttons, one changes the value, one just sets the same value. When setting the same value, you only see the Log.d of the local recomposition. When changing the state value, you see two log lines. the local and external both go through the recomposition.

```
@Composable
fun StackOverflowApp() {
    var state by remember { mutableStateOf(value = 0, policy = neverEqualPolicy()) }

Column() {
    Button(onClick = { state = state }) {
        Text(text = "State same value")
    }
    Button(onClick = { state += 1 }) {
        Text(text = "State up")
    }

    Text(text = "[local] current State = $state")
    Log.d("TAG","Recomposition local")
    ExternalText(state)
}
}

/**
 * A skippable function
 * 
 * restartable skippable scheme("[androidx.compose.ui.UiComposable]") fun ExternalText(
    stable state: Int
)
 */
@Composable
fun ExternalText(state: Int){
    Text(text = "[external] current State = $state")
    Log.d("TAG","Recomposition external")
}
```

You can also pass the MutableState instead of the int value itself, when you pass the mutableState, the neverEqualPolicy is still in play. Each interaction fires both log lines

```
@Composable
fun StackOverflowApp() {
    var state = remember { mutableStateOf(value = 0, policy = neverEqualPolicy()) }

    Column() {
        Button(onClick = { state.value = state.value }) {
            Text(text = "State same value")
        }
        Button(onClick = { state.value += 1 }) {
            Text(text = "State up")
        }

        Text(text = "[local] current State = ${state.value}")
        Log.d("TAG","Recomposition internal")
        ExternalText(state)
    }
}

@Composable
fun ExternalText(state: MutableState<Int>){
    Text(text = "[external] current State = ${state.value}")
    Log.d("TAG","Recomposition external")
}
```

Comment: I'm not understanding why Screen is skippable when I use the V1 functions and never skipped when I use the V2 functions. Thx for the link.

Comment: When using the V1 functions, the parameter for the Screen function never changes with the same interactions(always stays 0 or 2), the Screen function itself is (probably) defined/analysed as skippable, so if the parameter given to the function does not change, the function gets skipped. When using the V2 functions, the state will always change on interaction, with that the parameter for the screen function. Since the parameter changes, a recomposition will occur.

Comment: I think I now see my misunderstanding and that the "state" variable loses its value as a compose state variable when it is passed as an Int instead of as a MutableState. I will make changes to my code and come back to accept your answer if I have success. Thx for your patience.

Comment: Changing "state by remember{}" to "state = remember{}" so the variable is a MutableState instead of an Int made all the difference! It's amazing how easy it is to go to Norway these days and get some help! BTW, ChatGPT has been helpful for me on many beginner coding issues but didn't help me with this one.